# Which tag is semantically correct for ordered list with ex aequo positions - OL or UL?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

If a list is definitely ordered (ranking with positions), but some position numbers are doubled (because of ex aequo result), should an unordered list tag (UL) be used then, or still ordered list (OL)?

Comment: Not very much into the semantic rules myself, but I'd say `<li>`'s `value` attribute is there for that case (among others). https://jsfiddle.net/1eqpgkxj/

Comment: Of course! I was missing this piece. Thank you @Kaiido

Comment: While some questions about semantic markup are opinion-based, others (like this one) have definite, non-subjective answers. I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of a list matters, even if the order is non-standard, the list should be marked up with an [Ordered List element (`<ol>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol).

As [Kaiido points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66056393/which-tag-is-semantically-better-for-ordered-list-with-ex-aequo-positions-ol-o#comment116790232_66056393), the default numbering of list items can be altered by using the [`value` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#attributes).

The case of *ex aequo* (i.e., evenly placed or ["dead heat"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_heat)) results in a competition could be marked up like this:

```html
<ol>
  <li value="1">Penny Oleksiak</li>
  <li value="1">Simone Manuel</li>
  <li value="3">Sarah Sjöström</li>
</ol>
```